# NSArray to NSData encoding formatting

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsdata, messageui

I am putting together a program that reads the sensors within a cell phone and saves the sensor data to a core-data SQLite model, with each set of readings pertaining to a particular session

The program provides the user with the option to email a .csv file of a particular session.

Having never done this before, I approached the issue by initializing a delegate and context, and searching the core data for entities that pertain to a specified session.  The entities that satisfy the session attribute then have their data fields (gps, mag, accel, gyro) read and put into a string.  Then the string is appended to an array.  All done in swift.

After the entities are searched and the array is created, I attempt to create a csv file for attachment to an email.  The file is attached successfully, but my encoding technique is presenting additional data prepended and appended to the file.

I want to save a file on the phone and email a copy to the user.

Here is what I have to change the Array to NSArray before converting again to NSData:

```
    let paths: NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true);
    let path = paths[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("SessionData.csv")

    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path)
    {
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
    }

    var handle: NSFileHandle = NSFileHandle(forWritingAtPath: path)
    handle.truncateFileAtOffset(handle.seekToEndOfFile())
    var arrayToWriteNS = (arrayToWrite as NSArray)
    var dataNS: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(arrayToWrite as NSArray)
    handle.writeData(dataNS)

    mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
    mc.addAttachmentData(dataNS, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "SessionData.csv")
```

Here is the prepended and appended data:

```
bplist00‘()T$topX$objectsX$versionY$archiver—TrootÄ¨    
!U$null“
V$classZNS.objectsÄ©ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ    Ä
```

"My Data"

```
 “"#$'X$classesZ$classname¢%&WNSArrayXNSObjectWNSArrayÜ†_NSKeyedArchiver(25:<IOT[fhrtvxz|~ÄÇÑ·Ø}KÁµÉQV_jmu~Üã*ù
```

In a large data session with 28,000 entities there may be ~750 lines of prepended data.

Any help that you can provide would be appreciated.

I'm new to iOS, Obj-C, and swift, thus I'm positive there is a better way to do this, I just haven't discovered a better method yet.

Thank you.

UPDATE: Ended up just using the NSString data encoding and writing to my file in increments:

```
handle.truncateFileAtOffset(handle.seekToEndOfFile())
var stringToWriteNS = (stringToWrite as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
handle.writeData(stringToWriteNS!)
```

Comment: You do not want `NSKeyedArchiver`, it is for archiving and restoring classes. You need to go through the array and create a text representation of each item in a format you what to present to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want NSKeyedArchiver, it is for archiving and restoring classes.

You need to go through the array and create a text representation of each item in a format you what to present to the user.

A quick search of CocoaPods reveals [several projects](http://cocoapods.org/?q=csv) that may fit you needs to generate csv format data.

[This one](https://github.com/iotize/CSV#csv) might be what you need.

csv is fairly simple so it would be reasonable to format your data to csv by writing your own code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add CocoaPods to my search domain.  I ended up going with using the NSString encoding and writing to my file in increments, as the csv was easy to create on my own.